# Libinput extra mouse button mapping

Tags: mouse, xinput, button, xbindkeys

I have a Logitech M570 mouse connected to my laptop. I originally got the extra side buttons mapped to window overview in Gnome (the 'Super' key) by following instructions here on AskUbuntu to configure xbindkeys.

I then set about configuring touchpad gestures, again following instructions I found here. This required installing the libinput driver and libinput-gestures.

Now that the touchpad gestures are working as they should, the extra mouse buttons are no longer working. The side buttons have started behaving as 'Back' and 'Forward' buttons. I have searched the forums again but I'm at a loss. Running *xev*, the buttons are detected as follows:

```
ButtonRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x2a00001,
    root 0xee, subw 0x0, time 24449680, (32,94), root:(61,151),
    state 0x2010, button 9, same_screen YES

ButtonPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x2a00001,
    root 0xee, subw 0x0, time 24451078, (32,94), root:(61,151),
    state 0x2010, button 8, same_screen YES
```

Running *evemu-record* they are detected as:

```
E: 0.000000 0004 0004 589829    # EV_MSC / MSC_SCAN             589829
E: 0.000000 0001 0114 0001  # EV_KEY / BTN_EXTRA            1
E: 0.000000 0000 0000 0000  # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ----------
E: 0.101916 0004 0004 589829    # EV_MSC / MSC_SCAN             589829
E: 0.101916 0001 0114 0000  # EV_KEY / BTN_EXTRA            0
E: 0.101916 0000 0000 0000  # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ----------
E: 0.741926 0004 0004 589828    # EV_MSC / MSC_SCAN             589828
E: 0.741926 0001 0113 0001  # EV_KEY / BTN_SIDE             1
E: 0.741926 0000 0000 0000  # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ----------
E: 0.820012 0004 0004 589828    # EV_MSC / MSC_SCAN             589828
E: 0.820012 0001 0113 0000  # EV_KEY / BTN_SIDE             0
E: 0.820012 0000 0000 0000  # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ----------
```

However when I run *xbindkeys -k* the buttons are not detected.

Any idea what's going on here? It seems that xbindkeys doesn't play well with the libinput driver, but the other tools seem to pick up the events fine.